# Hibernate Criteria.list() takes a very long time for a very simple query

Tags: sql, performance, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

One of the applications that I'm looking after has this piece of code which is taking ~20,000 ms to execute. This is really hampering the performance of the Website. Is this because of a Criteria.list? Here's the code that's responsible for the slowness. I have a Sample DB table where I am trying to retrieve all the values in the table. How can I improve the performance of this query? I'm using a SQL server as my database.

```
public Map<Integer, Sample> getAllSamples() {
    Map<Integer, Sample> Sample = transactionTemplate
            .execute(new TransactionCallback<Map<Integer, Sample>>() {
                @Override
                public Map<Integer, Sample> doInTransaction(TransactionStatus arg0) {
                    Criteria criteria = hibernateTemplate
                            .getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                            .createCriteria(Sample.class);
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("deleted"));
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    List<Sample> Samples = (List<Sample>) criteria.list();
                    HashMap<Integer, Sample> mSamples = new HashMap<Integer, Sample>();
                    for (Sample sample: Samples){
                        if (sample != null && sample.getsampleId() != null){
                            //hibernateTemplate.initialize(sample);
                            mSamples.put(sample.getsampleId(), sample);
                            hibernateTemplate.initialize(sample.getsampleCountry());
                        }
                    }
                    return mSamples;
                }
            });
    return Sample;
}
```

Now, My Sample class has two other classes called Account and Deposit. The relationship between Sample and the other two are one to one. However, The fetchType is lazy. Here's the code in Sample class,

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sample", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public deposit getDeposit() {
    return this.deposit;
}
```

I checked the logs, and for each row in Sample, there is a query being generated in Deposit. How do I make sure that this is not the case? Since there are around 400 rows in Sample; For retrieving deposit, there are 400 queries run. This is weird. I'm not sure what can be done here for improving the performance. Any pointers would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use eager fetching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did. I made the association mandatory (optional = false), it trusts that for every sample record, there is going to be a Deposit record. Therefore, when loading Sample, Hibernate doesn't load Deposit table as well.

This is the underlying code,

```
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sample",         cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public deposit getDeposit() {
        return this.deposit;
    }
```